# Splat a list in to a function

Tags: python, list, function, parameters, splat

I have a list

`fb_param_list = ['Fb01', 'Fb02',..., 'Fb76', 'Fb77']` 62 elements in total

I want to use are a parameter into my function

```
def get_data(timeFrame,period,*args):
  for chute in args:
    try:
        ret = get   (Period=period,
                    DataSet=dataSet,
                    ServiceName=serviceName,
                    Metric=chute,
                    MethodName=methodName,
                    Marketplace=marketPlace,
                    StartTime=timeFrame,
                    Stat=stat)
        metric = ret[u'Datapoint']
        #print metric
        diverts = (sum([float(elem[u'Val']) for elem in metric]))
        print ('Diverts in the last ' + timeFrame + ' is: ' + str(diverts) + ' for ' + chute)
    except:
        diverts = "error you f'd up"
    finally:
        print diverts
```

then i call the function like this

`get_data('Fa60','-PT5M',*fb_param_list)`

all i end up with is 62 lines of `error you f'd up`

so my loop is working but I don't think i am passing the parameter to `Metric`

what am i getting wrong? Its worth noting that the other arguments in the `get` function are constants that are declared elsewhere but I know these work.  I have also tested this function by calling a single variable instead of using a list.

Comment: Catch the exception using `except Exception as e:` and `print(e)` to see what's going on - you're not helping yourself by silently masking what the error is.

Comment: it's generally good practice to have as few lines in a `try` block as possible, and limit which types of exceptions are caught to ones you already know why they are happening

Comment: Also, a function named `get...` should probably be *returning* a value, not printing it. It may not even need to catch the exception; the whole point of exception handling is to let someone else deal with a problem if there is nothing useful you can do about it.

Comment: you're both right, once i printed me exception i could see that when i call my function i was still calling one of the list parameters `Fa60` which was then passed to `Period` and is the wrong parameter for that call, thanks for opening my eyes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: i catch the exception because the lib i'm will break the script but i will eventually need to leave it running unattended in the background

Comment: hey Prune, sorry if you haven't understood my question but I think it is pretty clear what I was asking, and Jon Clements and Aaron have helped me work out my loop is working but by hiding my error i could not solve it

Answer (score 1):

Once I printed my exception using Jon Clements help

`except Exception e:`
`print (e)`

i saw my error

'Incorrect Period value: -PT5M`

I had not changed the way I was calling the function it now works by calling

`get_data('-PT5M','OneMinute',*fa_chute_list)` instead of `get_data('Fa60','-PT5M',*fb_param_list)`